# Condition For Invalid Pointer

Tags: c++

Invalid pointer is a pointer point to an address can't access by current program, if try to use invalid pointer, then OS will block it happen, in C++ Primer chapter 2 said

> Using an invalid pointer as a condition or in a comparison is undefined

but I am just try to compare pointers, not dereference them, how to explain that sentence in C++ Primer?

Comment: The simple explanation is "don't do it", that's it.

Comment: If the pointer is pointing to an invalid address why would you want to use it in any way?

Comment: What real-world use case would need that to be allowed? It's not clear what you are really asking, beyond an X/Y Question. Also "OS will block it [from] happen[ing]" is not the case; undefined behaviour is undefined, and your program might blow up your sink or make you tea, or it might do nothing, or it might run with seemingly correct results. As Sam said, the only real answer is "don't do it".

Comment: Becasue standard says so,... this way compiler and architecture designers does not have to take into acount complicated logic to implement handling of wrong addresses. The only 'wrong' address allowed is one past the array. The truth is on most architectures you will not get a crash, for example see here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/385f9b5636106ee7 , even clang with sanitization does not complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primer says the behavior is undefined.

In most cases leaving the behavior undefined is done because saying anything else (as in comparing an invalid pointer returns false) would mean some performance cost (extra memory, an extra check). It doesn't mean that the comparison will not return a result. It means that the compiler can do anything it wants at that point (this includes [time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)).

Since the compiler is allowed to do anything in this case, it can assume that both pointers are valid and skip checks for validity around them. It can assume that the result is whatever it allows it to remove most of the code (in case you use it in an if).

In addition, since at this point no one can tell you what the result of the comparison is, how can anyone argue that the program is correct (that is it will do what you say it's supposed to do)?

So:

- Can you compare invalid pointers? Sure.
- Is the result stable? Probably not.
- Will this crash? Maybe.
- Should you use it in a program? No. Avoid at all costs.

Comment: An (admittedly ancient) example comes from the days when Windows ran on the 386, and pointers (for some memory models) were represented in two parts: a segment and an offset. The segment value told the hardware where in your application the memory was located; if the segment wasn't valid and you tried to look at the value of the pointer you'd get a hardware exception, i.e., the program would crash.

Comment: So, what is an invalid pointer, it's just a pointer have address out of range or point to an address doesn't have any objects?

Comment: @AlanJian I don't know the exact definition, you'll have to look in the specification for that. If you call delete or if you have a pointer to an object that went out of scope, that would be invalid. There might be some corner cases with multithreading and in-place construction, better to check the specification.